# Como definir o diretório images e fonts no Laravel-mix?

Tags: webpack, laravel

Estou utilizando o Laravel-mix em um projeto pessoal, porém, sem a presença do Framework Laravel. Quando mando gerar os arquivos o Laravel-mix lê os arquivos sass e cria na raiz do projeto um diretório images e um fonts.

Como faço para definir o assets/img e assets/fonts respectivamente?